# create subset and use each atom only once

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I am totally new in asp. I need to create a group of teams. Each group must consist of 3 randomly chosen teams. A team can be in only one group.

Thanks in advance. Here is my code

```
team(fener;galata;besik;van;adana;mardin).

neq(X,Y) :- X!=Y,team(X),team(Y).

count(C) :- C = #count{ T : team(T)}.

C/3 {group(X,Y,Z):team(X),team(Y),team(Z), neq(X,Y),neq(X,Z),neq(Z,Y) } C/3 :- count(C).

#show group/3.
```

a possible output could be

```
group(fener;besik;van) group(galata;mardin;adana)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, have found the solution.

```
team(fener;galata;besik;van;adana;mardin).

neq(X,Y) :- X!=Y,team(X),team(Y).

count(C) :- C = #count{ T : team(T)}.

C/3 {group(X,Y,Z):team(X),team(Y),team(Z), neq(X,Y),neq(X,Z),neq(Z,Y) } C/3 :- count(C).

exist_in_group(T) :- group(T,_,_).
exist_in_group(T) :- group(_,T,_).
exist_in_group(T) :- group(_,_,T).

:- team(T), not exist_in_group(T).

#show group/3.
```

**The output:**

```
clingo version 5.0.0
Solving...
Answer: 1
group(besik,fener,adana) group(galata,mardin,van)
SATISFIABLE

Models       : 1+
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.011s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.000s
```

Answer (score 1):

The output you want is not possible:

```
group(a;b;c).
```

implies:

```
group(a). group(b). group(c).
```

A possible output would be:

```
group(a,b,c).
```

But ASP is not really friendly with variable arguments atoms, or list elements as parameters. A simpler output to manage would be:

```
group(1,a). group(1,b). group(1,c).
```

And this is very easy to generate, and allows us to avoid the costly `#count`:

```
% Data
#const nb_group=2.
group(1..nb_group).
team(fener;galata;besik;van;adana;mardin).

% Assign 3 teams to each group
3{ group(G,T): team(T) }3 :- group(G).

% Two (almost) equilavent constraints:
1{ group(G,T): group(G) }1:- team(T).  % a team is in only one group
OR
:- team(T) ; not group(_,T).  % a team has no group
```

Comment: Are you sure that the group(a;b;c) output is not possible, please try my answer to see if it is. 
I might have some logical errors but here it is.

Comment: Since you want two differentiated groups, you would lost the information. Try run clingo on `group(a;b;c). group(d;e;f).`. Can you determine which letter belong to which group ?

Comment: On the other hand, your answer use `group(a,b,c)`. To quote my own answer: *ASP is not really friendly with variable arguments atoms, or list elements as parameters*. That's the reason i propose another way to go.